# Stamp format in Mongo db/Robo 3t?

Tags: java, mongodb, date, timestamp, robo3t

I have certain object that has a date property. When i print the date value in Java i get a normal date like "11/08/2021". The thing is, when i try to check the date of my object (which is stored in mongoDB) in Robo 3T, i get a number like that : 1507037760657.

I searched and i found this kind of [converter](http://www.timestamp.fr/) that allows to convert timeStamp format to date format. But that value : 1507037760657 is converted to some really weird date like 15/2/49726.

Is mongoDB using another timestamp format i don't know? How can i get a good date from  this number ? 1507037760657

Thanks

Comment: Check settings of your Robo 3T, usually you can can define the date format in your user preferences - provided the values are really stored as `Date` object and not something else.

Comment: Tuesday 3 October 2017 13:36:00.657 UTC? If so, those are milliseconds since the Unix epoch where your conversion service took them as seconds. Said not knowing Robo 3T,